# In haskell, how to transfer the functions defined without do notation to the function defined with do?

Tags: haskell, types

I am new in Haskell. Now I have some problems about type.
It is said that the function:

```
fg a tb tc = case lookup a tb of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just b -> case lookup b tc of
        Nothing -> Nothing
        Just c -> Just [b,c]
```

is the same as the function:

```
fg' a tb tc = do
    b <- lookup a tb
    c <- lookup b tc
    Just [b,c]
```

Their type are both fg :: (Eq t, Eq a) => a -> [(a, t)] -> [(t, t)] -> Maybe [t]

However, the function below is treated as a different one:

```
fg'' a tb tc = do
    let     
        b = lookup a tb
        c = lookup b tc
    Just [b,c]
```

Its type is fg'':: (Eq b, Eq a) => a -> [(a, b)] -> [(Maybe b, b)] -> Maybe [Maybe b].
These confuses me. Do anyone can explain why?

Comment: Try to desugar the `do` notation. You will see that `fg'` and `fg''` look _very_ different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're saying that `b = lookup a tb`.  This means that `b` has the same type as `lookup a tb`, and `lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b`.  So `b :: Maybe b`.  Next, `c = lookup b tc` means that `c` has the same type as `lookup b tc`.  Since `b :: Maybe b`, `lookup b :: [(Maybe b, c)] -> Maybe c` (remember that the type variables chosen are irrelevant, so long as they're consistent), and `c :: Maybe c`.  Since lists in Haskell are homogeneous, `[b, c]` means that `b` and `c` have the same type, so `Maybe b ~ Maybe c` implies `b ~ c`.  Since `fg''` returns a value of `Just [b, c]`, this means that `Just [b, c] :: Maybe [Maybe b]`.

The `<-` syntax in Haskell is not equivalent to `=` in a `let`.  In your case, `fg'` could be turned into a function without `do` using the `>>=` operator, which for `Maybe` has the type

```
(>>=) :: Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
```

And can be used as

```
fg''' a tb tc =
    lookup a tb >>= (\b ->            -- b <- lookup a tb
        lookup b tc >>= (\c ->        -- c <- lookup b tc
            Just [b, c]               -- Just [b, c]
        )
    )
```

Think of `>>=` as feeding the value wrapped in a monad forward into a function that returns a new monadic value.  For `Maybe`, this operator will short circuit if the `Maybe a` turns out to be `Nothing`, since it won't have a value to feed forward into the `(a -> Maybe b)`.

Answer (score 3):

The monad laws ensure that

```
do x <- return y   -- note the return here
   ...
```

is equivalent to

```
do let x = y
   ...
```

Note, however, that without the `return` above, the two `x`s in the code above have a different type, so they can never be equivalent. This is because if `y :: m a`, then the first piece of code has `x :: a`, while the second uses `x :: m a`, and `a` and `m a` are always different types.

For instance,

```
do x <- [1]
   return x
```

evaluates to `[1]`. Instead,

```
do let x = [1]
   return x
```

evaluates to `[[1]]`.

Answer (score 1):

In `do` notation, the `<-` takes the value out of the `Monad` (`Maybe` in this case) and let's you manipulate that value in the code that follows.
But that's not the only thing that it does.

It also applies the 'characteristic' of the `Monad` in question. The characteristic of maybe is that if the value on the right side of the arrow is `Nothing`, it doesn't do any unwrapping (because there's nothing to unwrap) and just fails the whole computation, so that the result of the whole thing is also `Nothing`.

A `let` binding doesn't do anything like that. It just assigns a new name to some existing value so when you do `let a = lookup b tb` the `a` is still of the type `Maybe something`. On the other hand, when you unwrap it like `a <- lookup b tb`, the type of `a` is `something`.